# Variable with colon dash ${VAR:-}

Tags: shell, arguments, variable-substitution

How does "${2:-}" work in an 'if-then-else example' below?  Somehow I cannot help but think that being ${2:-} it means the second argument, but I am curious what the colon(:) and dash(-) after the digit 2 mean?

```
  if [ "${2:-}" = "Y" ]; then
     prompt="Y/n"
     default=Y
  elif [ "${2:-}" = "N" ]; then
     prompt="y/N"
     default=N
  else
     prompt="y/n"
     default=
  fi

  read -p "$1 [$prompt] " REPLY </dev/tty
```

Answer (score 16):

The syntax `${VAR:-default}` evaluates to the value of `VAR` or, if it is unset or null, it evaluates to the text after the hyphen (in this case, `default`); the syntax `${VAR- default}` is similar shortened of the a similar function *only* for when the variable is unset. `$2` is a positional parameter, so your statement is testing the value of the second argument, and if it is not set, using an empty value as a default.

Why use an empty default, since that would have the same effect as a plain `$2`? Because under `set -u` (equivalent to `set -o nounset`), substituting an unset variable causes an error: if there are less than 2 parameters, `$2` errors out. But `${2:-}` won't error out, because it explicitly substitutes the empty string if the parameter is unset or null.

Comment: [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: which begs the question, how `${2:-}` differs from `${2}` which also has an empty expansion if it's empty or unset.

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether the context of this section of the script has `set -u` in place (:

Comment: It has a 'set -o nounset' at the very beginning of the script, would that be the same as 'set -u'?

Comment: Yes, the latter is shorthand for the former.